# File validation rules

Tags: design-patterns, data, parsing, validation, rules-engine

I have an application that can accept CSV files to run some operations. The files look like:

```
CREATE USER:username,last_name,first_name,age
user1,Smith,John,23
user2,Poppins,Mary,257
```

There are a number of commands that can be used, each with a specific "syntax" in terms of what columns are required / authorised, the type of data in each column, valid values as well as more complex rules (e.g. 2 users can't have the same username, the username must not already be present in the database, etc.).

At the moment, each of those commands correspond to a specific class in my OO model which runs the validation with code (`if (type(column) != STRING) blabla`) before executing the commands.

This is becoming cumbersome and I would like to extract the validation rules in human readable format, say:

```
Command=CREATE USER
Field='username', required, text, max_length=255, min_length=1,
      unique, not exists in db table 'User'
Field='age', optional, number, min=0, max=120
....
```

My code could then become:

```
List<Error> errors = validate(csvFile, rulesFile);
if (errors.isEmpty()) //good to go
```

However the more I think about it, the more it seems like it's going to be a major headache to code and effectively a whole project in itself, possibly not worth the time spent.

What approach could I take to extract rules in human readable format without unduly complicating the validation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around. -- Eric S. Raymond, *The Cathedral and the Bazaar*

You can use XML or JSON with schemas. Validation rules should be machine-readable first, and human-readable if possible. Consider [*not* inventing your own format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) and using [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) or [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) instead. Switching to XML/JSON should not be very difficult, since there are a lot of libs available.

What you have now is basically some form of [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) based on CSV format. Maybe you should look into [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) or something similar.